# Issue in display particular Notification message in my application

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

Hello frineds i want to display my particular notification  message in my application screen so below is my code

**Main.java**

```
public class NewMain extends Activity  {
// This is a handle so that we can call methods on our service
 // This is the date picker used to select the date for our notification
private DatePicker picker;

 int notificationCount;
 String mStringTimeNotification="";
GetSecrateKey mGetSecrateKey;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
PostParseGet mPostParseGet;
String mStringNewPass="";
    String mStringOldPass="";
EditText mEditTextTitle;
EditText mEditTextDesc;
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutDate;
TextView mTextViewDate;
Calendar mCalendar;
Button mTextViewSave;
AllMethods mAllMethods;
boolean isClick=false;
int day,month,year,fday,fmm,fyy;
EditText mEditTextDate;
ImageView mImageViewBack;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_layout);
    mTextViewMyAccount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.titel_user);
    // Create a new service client and bind our activity to this service
    mPostParseGet=new PostParseGet(NewMain.this);
     mAllMethods=new AllMethods(NewMain.this);
    mLinearLayoutDate=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_date);
    mEditTextDesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_desc);
    mGetSecrateKey=new GetSecrateKey();
    mEditTextTitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_title);
    mTextViewSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    mEditTextDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_degree);
    mImageViewBack=(ImageView )findViewById(R.id.img_back);
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.MY_PREF, 0);
    mStringGetSecrateKey=mSharedPreferences.getString("secratekey", ""); 
    mTextViewMyAccount.setText(MyeHealthApplication.mStringUsername);
    fday=day;
    fmm=month+1;
    fyy=year;
    mEditTextDate.setText(String.valueOf(day)+"/"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"/"+String.valueOf(year));





    mTextViewSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mEditTextTitle.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mAllMethods.ShowDialog(NewMain.this, "Validation error", "Enter title", "OK");
            }
            else {
                if (isClick==true) {
                    fday = picker.getDayOfMonth();
                    fmm = picker.getMonth();
                    fyy = picker.getYear();
                    isClick=false;
                    setReminder(fyy, fmm, fday, 0, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(NewMain.this, "Notification set for: "+ fday +"/"+ (fmm+1) +"/"+ fyy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {

                    setReminder(year, month, day, 0, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(NewMain.this, "Notification set for: "+ day +"/"+ (month+1) +"/"+ year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
    mLinearLayoutDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDialogPin.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_rim_date);
        picker=(DatePicker)mDialogPin.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        TextView mTextViewsave=(TextView)mDialogPin.findViewById(R.id.dialog_save);
        mTextViewsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                isClick=true;
                mDialogPin.dismiss();
                fday = picker.getDayOfMonth();
                fmm = picker.getMonth();
                fyy = picker.getYear();

                mEditTextDate.setText(String.valueOf(fday) +"/"+ (String.valueOf(fmm+1)) +"/"+ String.valueOf(fyy));
            }
        });
        mDialogPin.show();
        }
    });
}



public void setReminder( int year,int month,int day,int hour,int minite)
   {


           notificationCount  = notificationCount+1;
           String[] parts = mEditTextDate.getText().toString().trim().split("/");
           String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
           String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
           String part3 = parts[2];

           System.out.println("part1 "+part1);
           System.out.println("part2 "+part2);
           System.out.println("part3 "+part3);


            year=Integer.parseInt(part1);
            month=Integer.parseInt(part2);
            day=Integer.parseInt(part3);

            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
               String aFormatted = formatter.format(month);
               String aFormatted1 = formatter.format(day);
               String aFormatted2 =formatter.format(hour);
               String aFormatted3 =formatter.format(minite);
           mStringTimeNotification=year+"-"+aFormatted+"-"+aFormatted1+" "+aFormatted2+"-"+aFormatted3;
           System.out.println("Sett DAteTiem " +mStringTimeNotification);

     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm");  
           Date dt = null;
       try {
            dt = df.parse(mStringTimeNotification);
        }
       catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }                                        
        long when = dt.getTime();  
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NewMain.this, ReminderAlarm.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Name",mEditTextTitle.getText().toString().trim());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("Description",mEditTextDesc.getText().toString().trim()+" at "+mEditTextDate.getText().toString().trim());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount",notificationCount );

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NewMain.this, notificationCount, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, pi);


   }


  }
```

**ReminderAlarm.java**

```
  public class ReminderAlarm  extends BroadcastReceiver{
  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
   private Notification notification;   

   @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
      CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
      Intent notificationIntent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
      notificationIntent1.putExtra("Name", from);
      notificationIntent1.putExtra("Description", message);
      notificationIntent1.putExtra("NotifyCount", intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount").toString());

      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent1, 0);
      RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_first, from);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.noti_second, message);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentTitle(from).setContentText(message).build();
      notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
      mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount").toString()), notification);        
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Notification Received",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

   }
 }
```

**NotificationView.java**

```
public class NotificationView extends Activity  {
String title;
String text;
TextView txttitle;
TextView txttext;
String noti;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notificationview);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        title = i.getStringExtra("Name");
        text = i.getStringExtra("Description");
        noti =i.getStringExtra("NotifyCount");
        System.out.println("title "+title);
        System.out.println("text "+text);
        System.out.println("noti "+noti);
        // Locate the TextView
        txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        txttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        txttitle.setText("Title : "+title);
        txttext.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Description :</b>"+" "+text) );

}


}
```

When i run above code first notification is shows correct in my **Notificationview.java** class but when i make second notification and click over that it will display first notification which i make, it not updated notification display in **notificationview.java** class any idea how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement override method in your NotificationView class.

```
/**
 * Method to decide which detail view should be called on the basis of
 * notification when notification is clicked.
 * @param intent
 */
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
             title = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
             text = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
             noti = intent.getStringExtra("NotifyCount");

    // Locate the TextView
    txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    txttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    txttitle.setText("Title : "+title);
    txttext.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Description :</b>"+" "+text) );
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In your onCreate method, call `onNewIntent(getActivity().getIntent());`

Hopefully it works.

Comment: :as per your suggestion i make a change same but still not update notification detail in NotificationVIew.java .. pls. check below link and tell me if i make any wronge on that [http://pastebin.com/j0Enq8Th](http://pastebin.com/j0Enq8Th)

Comment: in your onRecieve method, change PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent1, 0); to PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notificationIntent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); also add notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); betore PendingIntent intialization.

Comment: Hello Karan check this link [http://pastebin.com/mdrGn5NC](http://pastebin.com/mdrGn5NC) and tell me any wrong because i change as per your suggestion but still not update

Comment: I think the problem would be notificationCount increment, increase its value into onRecieve method and passed it as notify() method parameter.Let me know if this works or not, otherwise will make a sample app with your code and will solved it.

Comment: Yes Brother ,, Your are right problem is in notification count , now i increase it is working fine !! Thanks for your time and effort .. and also +1 for your answer ....